# Is there a method such as pandas' iloc() and cumsum() for a DataFrame in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have been working on an Actuarial Science method called the Chain Ladder method for which the code is as follows:

[image: full_triangle(f,ft,n)]

Here,

- `f` is a list of float values
- `ft` is the DataFrame.
- `n` is the number of rows/columns since `ft` is a square matrix kind of DataFrame.

`ft` is a DataFrame which earlier looked like this :

[image: Incremental Triangle Data Frame of ft]

Later, cumulative summation method was applied to this DataFrame in order to pass it into the `full_triangle` function:

```
ft = ft.cumsum(axis=1)
```

After the above method the triangle looks like this:

[image: Cumulative Summation Triangle Data Frame of ft]

Then, I applied this:

```
ft = full_triangle(f, ft, n)
```

After the method is applied on `ft`, it looks like this:

[image: Complete Triangle ft]

Now my question is:  Are there any such similar methods such as `iloc()` and `cumsum()` for a `pyspark` DataFrame?

Please help me out.

Comment: `iloc` is probably a simple [`where`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where). `cumsum` is a [`sum`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum) with a [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window).

Comment: please avoid code/data as image. You can format your code or data directly with MD language.

Comment: apparently, your code is really sequential. It won't work as-is with spark, as spark works in set programming. The logic is not the same. You cannot simply replace the functions from pandas to spark.

Comment: Thanks @Steven for the help. I am new to being a stack overflow user so it's gonna take a bit of time to learn to properly use it. With regards to my code being sequential, well it's because I directly converted the mathematical method into code rather than using the chainladder package in python as per my project guide's instructions. So I can't help it really.

Comment: Thanks Harry Plotter for editing the question.